# How can I change mouse cursor on the components which have a context menu event handler?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need some way to inform user that he can right click on some component. 
How can I change mouse cursor on the components which have a context menu event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `cls` of the component to a CSS class that would contain `cursor:...` rule.